# Debian яркость на ноуте HP Pavilion G6

Tags: linux, debian, amd, radeon

Есть у меня ноутбук  HP pavilion g6 установил на него DEBIAN 8

```
GNOME 3.14.1
AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)
Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-бит
```

И никак не могу яркость поменять: клавиши системные не работают. Справа вверху, если нажать есть ползунок яркости, он двигаается но яркость не меняется (а ползунок громкости - громкость меняет)

Команды

```
root@debian:/home/miha# setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=01
root@debian:/home/miha# setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=09
root@debian:/home/miha# setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=99
```

Ничего не дают.

В настройках grub выставил

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

После update grub и перезагрузка. И ползунок пропал. Только громкость осталось...

Папка

```
/sys/class/backlight/
```

пустая

Установка и команды xbacklight тоже без результата
    apt-get install xbacklight
    xbacklight -set 100
    xbacklight -set 1

Может что посоветуете?

Comment: `update-grub` запускали?

Comment: @sercxjo да, делал и перезагружал, спасибо за уточнение.